# How to reduce redundant cells in a column containing logged data

Tags: mysql, excel, database, algorithm, redundancy

Is there a function to reduce the amount of redundant data from one column to match the number of cells in a second column?

I have logged data from two sensors that sent values at different rates. in 8 hours, I collected 11857 values for the first sensor and 8130 for the second one.

I need to compress the first column by deleting data to match the number of cells on the second column, so I can display synchronized values on a chart.
It is not a matter of cutting 3727 cells from the head or tail of the first column, but to delete cells in a proportional way.

I've tried using de Modulus function, but it does not give me the right amount of compression; e.g., by running =MOD(A1,3) and then filtering cells containing '0' value and deleting those rows, I get 7905, which is close to 8130 but still, the data is shifted out.

**Edit:**

I found a method that requires several steps:

1. Copy the sensors' data into two columns
2. Get the number of cells for both columns using **COUNTA**
3. Get the **ratio** between the smaller count over the bigger count
4. In a new column, create an **index** for the rows using `=INT(ROW()*ratio)`
5. Remove duplicate rows using the **index** column as the reference with *Data > Remove Duplicates*
   It works, but it will be much faster if there was a ready-made function that will run over the provided data columns and copy the values into two new columns

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with mysql if it did the number of ROWS would be the same (assuming the 2 sensors data is in the same table).

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet?

Comment: Zac, this is the data: https://pastebin.com/dp8upqvs

Comment: P.Salmon, I log the data into .csv files, then open it in Excel for filtering, and finally import that into a table in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this solution in LibreOffice Calc. The functions used are basic enough to be found in Excel as well.

Here's a sample with data from 2 sensors, s1 and s2, similar to yours:

```
Row s1  s2
1   2   3
2   4   6
3   6   9
4   8   12
5   10  15
6   12  18
7   14  21
8   16  
9   18  
10  20  
11  22
```

What I did was match the data from s1 samples with those from s2 that relatively match the position of the first, so instead of ending up with a number of rows with no s2 values, I padded non-existent s2 values with the last sample taken for any given period of time (column s2a)

```
Row s1  s2  s2a
1   2   3   3
2   4   6   6
3   6   9   6
4   8   12  9
5   10  15  12
6   12  18  12
7   14  21  15
8   16      18
9   18      18
10  20      21
11  22      21
```

Assuming that s1 is column A and s2 is column B in the spreadsheet, the function you want on each cell of the new column is:

```
=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( CEILING( ROW()* COUNT(B:B)/COUNT(A:A)),2))
```

Let's go from bottom to top:

- COUNT(B:B)/COUNT(A:A) - this is the ratio. 0.63' above. It indicates that each sample in any given row in s1 will be found at that row x 0.63 in column s2.
- Ceiling - Spreadsheets don't start at row 0, so the first one HAS to be 1. I experimented with Int(), but if the ratio were less than 0.5 we would end up with a 0, which we don't want.
- Address - Returns a string with the address of a cell given its row,column coordinates (e.g. Address(3, 2) = "B3" and Address(3,2,2) as used here, will yield an absolute column or "$B3").
- Indirect - Returns the contents of a cell whose address is passed as a string (e.g. Address("x5") will return whatever value is stored in cell X5).

Alex